# Get latest revision of snap package

Tags: snap, 21.10

Is possible to get latest revision of snap package in short form ?

Something like `snap info package`, but output only latest revision number.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 2):

If you want *just* the version number for a given snap, then you can do this:

```
snap list | grep package | awk '{print $2}'
```

Using this for `vlc` (on my system) results in the following value: `3.0.16`.

---

**How This works:**

| Command | Action |
| --- | --- |
| `snap list` | List all snaps |
| `|` | and |
| `grep package` | Grab line(s) matching `package` |
| `|` | and |
| `awk '{print $2}'` | Return *just* the second column (version) |

Comment: Revision number ans version number are not the same thing, though the revision number is also listed but in the third field...

Answer (score 0):

As wrote mook765, revision number is different from version number. But method used by **matigo** may be modified to get revision number:

```
$snap info vlc|awk '/latest\/stable/ {gsub("[()]","",$4);print $4 }'
2344
```

From unknown reason this script works slow, you may use this:

```
snap info vlc|perl -ane 'if (/latest\/stable/) { $F[3]=~ /(\d+)/; print($1);}'
```